# Get unique records using order by in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, distinct

```
ID    OrderId  status
    1  12       1
    2  13       1
    3  14       2
    4  12       3
    5  15       1
    6  14       1
```

hi all,

trying to build sql query for table like above to get result like below :

```
   OrderId  status
         12       3
         13       1
         14       1
         15       1
```

I want unique orderid with latest status code

I have tried this query

```
Select Distinct OrderID 
from OrdersStatusHistory 
order by Status desc
```

getting records but with repeating orderid

```
Select OrderID, Status 
from Orders_Status_History 
order by Status desc
```

But I'm getting an error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select OrdersStatusHistory.* from OrdersStatusHistory
JOIN
 (select OrderId, max(id) maxId 
      from OrdersStatusHistory 
      group by OrderId) t1
 on OrdersStatusHistory.Id=t1.maxId
 order by OrdersStatusHistory.OrderId
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3f6a/2)

or if you need juts maximum status for the `OrdeId`

```
select OrderId,max(status)
from OrdersStatusHistory
group by OrderID
order by OrderId
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your desired result wrong? `14` occurs twice, but the latest status is `2`.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY OrderId ORDER BY ID DESC) , OrderId, status
   FROM dbo.Orders
)
SELECT  OrderId, status FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efdef/2/0)

```
ORDERID STATUS
12          3
13          1
14          1  
15          1
```

Comment: @sharad: But 14 occurs twice, the latest status is 2 not 1. (see my edit)

Comment: @MarkBannister: However, but OP has stated clearly in his question that he _"want unique orderid with **latest status** code"_

Comment: Tim Schmelter,for  14 first status code was 2 later it becomes 1 so i want the latest status for particular orderid i.e. 1

Comment: @sharad: Then Mark Bannistar is proved right. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
Select orderid
,status 
from orders_status_history
where rowid in (Select max(rowid) 
from orders_status_history
group by orderid) order by order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this:

```
Select DISTINCT OrderID, Status from Orders_Status_History
```